# How to use Linq to combine strings and lists?

Tags: c#, linq

Novice linq user but prim_clus_list &ref_clus_list are a List and ref_clus & prim_clus are strings. I'm trying to do the following but it's not working.

```
string[] clus_list = prim_clus_list.Union(ref_clus_list).Union(ref_clus.ToList()).Union(prim_clus.ToList()).ToArray<string>();
```

How can I do this in one line? I want them all in one list with no duplicates.

CS1928: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Union(System.Linq.IQueryable, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments

Also this alone works fine:

```
string[] clus_list = prim_clus_list.Union(ref_clus_list).ToArray<string>();
```

Comment: If `ref_clus` is `string`, then `ref_clus.ToList().ToList()` shouldn't compile, unless you have extension methods for string

Comment: Yep, sorry, left out the error. Updated.

Comment: If you are novice then you should read documentation of linq, union and string first

Comment: Use Linq aggregate

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya - if we read documentation carefully, we don't need StackOverflow then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
var prim_clus_list = new List<string>() { "A", "B" };
var ref_clus_list = new List<string>() { "C", "D" };
var ref_clus = "E";
var prim_clus = "F";

string[] clus_list =
    prim_clus_list
        .Union(ref_clus_list)
        .Union(new [] { ref_clus })
        .Union(new [] { prim_clus })
        .ToArray<string>();
```

That gives:

```
A 
B 
C 
D 
E 
F
```

Basically `ref_clus.ToList()` returns a `List<char>`, but `new [] { ref_clus }` returns an `IEnumerable<string>` which can be used with `.Union`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.Append` method to append single item to `IEnumerable`

```
var result = prim_clus_list.Append(ref_clus)
                           .Append(prim_clus)
                           .Union(ref_clus_list)
                           .ToArray();
```

Put `Union` in the end of the chain to get rid of duplicates.

[Enumerable.Append(IEnumerable, TSource) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Append__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____0_)

Comment: I get an `CS0023 Operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type 'void'` error when I try this code?

Comment: My bad. I had a rogue extension method that was taking precedence.